# Strange Behavior with pointers with arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Hello people of Stacked Overflow! Recently I've been learning about pointers and arrays in my college Computer Science class. In order to try to test the depth of my understanding of the two, I tried to come up with some confusing instances in order to see if I could correctly predict the outcome of the result, as well as the reason for why the result is what it is... Well I seem to have confused myself too much, because I don't understand these few instances that I have come up with.

```
int vals[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int* valptr = vals;

cout<<*valptr<<endl;
cout<<(**&vals)+1<<endl;
//cout<<*(++valptr)<<endl;
// cout<<*(++vals)<<end1;
cout<<*&valptr[0]<<endl;
cout<<**(&valptr)<<endl;
cout<<valptr[0]<<endl;
```

Part of the main part of my confusion was solved, so I commented out a line on the code, I wanted to know why lines such as `cout<<**(&valptr)<<endl;` actually run, I'm just confused on why that works. why does it only work when I have the & on it?

Comment: The first value is 1 to which you add 1. The second line prints the first element plus 1 it doesn't print the second element. Then you `++` the pointer which makes it point to the second element for the rest of the outputs.

Comment: This is why I usually fills such arrays with values like `[10, 20, 60, 500]`. It makes unexpected numbers like `11` or `59` much easier to track down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm very confusing seeing as in nowhere in that short code am I
> assigning anything further.

Not quite, you are, indeed, assigning a new value "further". You are doing it right here:

```
cout<<*(++valptr)<<endl;
```

In C++, the `++` operator ***increments*** its operand. The expression

```
++valptr
```

by itself is logically equivalent to `valptr=valptr+1`, but it occurs as part of the expression. `valptr` gets increment ***to a new value*** as part of the expression that it occurs in. That's what `++` does. You can also make a pretty good guess what the `--` operator does, too. And `++` and `--` works differently when it occurs before or after its operand, but that's slightly off-topic and is something you can investigate on your own, with your C++ textbook's help.

And this is exactly where you are "assigning anything further". So, `*valptr` before, and after this line, produces a different result.

Comment: I'm stupid, I forgot that yes, doing ++ would set the value of it equal to itself plus 1. However, I'm still confused on how lines such as ```cout<<**(&valptr)<<endl;``` even run at all, given that I can't really understand the syntax of it at all, and am not sure why it works.

Comment: You can figure it out one step at a time. Do you know what the unary `&` operator does? Do you know what the unary `*` operator does? Can you explain what each one of these operators do, in your own words? Now, simply start with `valptr`, apply the `&` operator then the `*` operator twice. Remember that these unary operators are right-associative. Once you do this, step by step, the end result should be pretty clear. If it's not clear, you should explain (perhaps in a new question) exactly what's unclear about this expression. One question per Stackoverflow question, please.

Comment: And no, you are not stupid. C++ is the most complicated and the hardest to learn general purpose programming language in use today. You need to understand that you will need to invest a long of time learning it. Everyone does. Don't rush. Slow down. Approach a solution to each problem, one small step at a time.

Comment: I know that & refers to an address, whereas * refers to the value at an address, but I've only used & when setting a pointer equal to the address of a variable, or when calling variables by reference, I'm not sure what It does in the specific instance that I have set up with it.

Comment: `&` takes an address. That's it. End of story. That's all it does. "Setting a pointer" is a separate story. That's what the `=` does. So, `&` takes an address, and `*` dereferences an address. Therefore, take a wild guess what `*&valptr` does. Well, obviously, it's: "absolutely nothing whatsoever". Take an address first, then dereference that address, you end up exactly where you started. Then another `*` just dereferences the address again. All `*` work the same (except when they don't, but you'll learn that in a couple of months). So, `**&valptr` does exactly the same as `*valptr`. The End.